# Adding search form to top navbar bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add search form to the top navbar code shown below so that it will appear just before the Logout link with a small space and aligned to the right side, but it always appear either after the logout link or it will expand the navbar and look bad.

So can someone please help me by telling me what I am missing here? Thanks for your time.

Head section:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
```

Body section:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">  
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">      
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>               
      <li class="active dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Employees <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">New Employee</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="nav-header">Reports</li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Employees List</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>                   
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">    

    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 

      <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>      
    </ul>
  </div>   
</nav>
```

Comment: Your html seems to be invalid... some unclosed divs.

Comment: It is really a huge page where this code reside, so I just added that code related to the navbar since the rest is totally irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put a `<form>` inside of an `<ul>` but not wrapped in a `<li>` so here is what seems to work:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upF8R/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="current">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Employees <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">New Employee</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Reports</li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">Employees List</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="#">logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now the positing is great, but the Logout link is now in blue not like Employees link for example, so is there anyway I can keep it as it was before (just like Employee link)? I tried adding ul/ li inside the form for the logout link but it messed up the look of the navbar